# Why can't I return a list when the function is called in another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the list at the end of my code. But, I can't seem to figure out how to return the list when it is called inside another function.

This is my code so far:

```
def main():
    select()
    print(list1, list2)
def select():
    select = 0
    select = int(input('Select one of the following: \n'
                   '(1) for list one \n'
                   '(2) for list two'))
    try:
        if select == 1:
            one()
        elif select == 2:
            two()
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
def one():
    list1 = []
    list1.append(1)
    return list1
def two():
    list2 = []
    list2.append(1)
    list2.append(2)
    return list2
def print(list1, list2):
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
main()
```

Comment: You aren't returning it from `select`. Also naming a function `print` is just *a bad idea* (Recursions ahoy).

Comment: Me: *code code code* `def print` *groan*

Answer (score 4):

You need to `return` the values of `one()` and `two()`, otherwise you're calling them and throwing their return values away.

```
if select == 1:
    return one()
elif select == 2:
    return two()
```

Same thing in `main()` when you call `select()`. You need to do something with the return value.

```
def main():
    result = select()
    print(result)
```

Get rid of your `print()` function. You don't want to shadow the built-in one.

```
def print(list1, list2):
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
```